# steps to use sim5360

Tags: gps, gsm

Actually i am new to use SIM5360 module.I have list down some points which i want to process by this module.If any one can guide me.It will be great for me.

> I want to check location by getting latitude and longitude value.
>   I want to send some data to the webserver by TCP socket communication.

```
Now,i have some doubts.Which i have list down as below:
```

> Can i send AT command directly and get latitude,longitude value.
>   Is there any steps require before establish TCP socket communication to send data to the server.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Kishan Patel.

Answer (score 0):

If you use location (I'm guessing GSM location, not GPS), TCP, UDP, FTP or other internet or network relevant features first you will need to be the state that feature needs.

For TCP connection you **cannot** just connect to an IP address without being attached to internet or you cannot send SMS without being registered to GSM network.

Also some features requires SSL connection or bearer connection.

I suggest you to go through [Application Notes](http://simcom.ee/documents/?dir=SIM5360) and see the requirement of each feature and read the AT command set for feature you need and test it manually by sending AT command sequentially from Serial Terminal to understand the meanings.

Best Regards

SBT

Comment: I have seen Application Notes as you told.In that process,first we have to check GPRS network by executing "AT+CSQ".I got "+CSQ:0,99".It means that network issue.
     So,what should be issue behind that.Have to require any step for GPRS network or it would be automatically start?.

Thanks.

Comment: CSQ used to get RSSI which is signal strength. Gprs is a different and you have problem with gsm attachment. Use AT+CREG=0 and wait for a while. And try AT+CREG? To see the network status. What is the net light status is it trying to blink ever? Are you using custom design board?

Comment: Hello Sbtek,I am using custom design board.I have followed command as you told "AT+CREG". But led is not blinking.Its continuously ON.

Comment: Hi, so it’s awkward. So what is AT+CREG? response?

Comment: Its resonse: '0'.

Comment: I suggest you to check hw. It does not make sense that led turned on constantly and creg 0. You can may be share hw. I can check it.

Comment: Ok. Have you require schematic or what?    And clarify me one thing if hw is proper and we configure "AT+CREG=0",then led will automatically blink(no need to execute any other AT command for network).Right?

Comment: When AT+CREG? is sent response must be +CREG 0,1 or 0,5 (roaming) but you get 0 it is really awkward. Are you getting any SMS ready or Call Ready string? For hardware large tantalum capacitors are needed to provide large current when registering to the network. That’s why i said Problem seems to  be hw. Can you try that commands and send me the results? AT+CFUN=1. AT+CREG=0. AT+CREG? (Send this for 6-7 times it can take up to 1 mins to connect) and ensure you have proper gsm antenna

Comment: Led blinking depends on your hw implementation. For reference design for LED_WWAN it must be off during module not connected to network. But you say it is constantly on

Comment: Ohh, i had post half response:i got response as 0,1.

Comment: check LED_WWAN# Reference Circuit if your status led is connected properly. it sound to me you are looking at power led and you did not connect WWAN led

Comment: Ok.But i can not understand point of LED_WWAN.In datasheet,there is only one LED is connected(which use GPIO1).

Comment: Thats a pin that indicates network status. Check hardware manual. Probably your led is just connected to power so it does not indicate

Comment: No,it is connected as in circuit from datasheet.

Comment: Can you share circuit from datasheet?

Comment: Ok."http://www.sabreadv.com/wp-content/uploads/SIM5360_Hardware_Design_V1.03.pdf"...this is a link.Please check on page number 41.

Comment: Send AT+CGFUNC=1,1 to open network status led feature

Comment: Ok. Actually, i have gave h/w to h/w team. When i will get it back, i will check this command.

Comment: Hello sbtek,Now we can see that led is blinking.And when i try to execute "AT+CSQ",i got respond like as "22,99" / "18,99" / "20,99".        And when execute "AT+CREG", respond is "0,1"

Comment: It’s great. AT CREG: 0,1 means connected try CSQ after connected it must be different than 99.

Comment: It always shows _,99. But i can send data on server_web site threw TCP/IP. But i am confusing about GPS data. It takes 1 to 2 hrs to lock and sometimes it could not lock. What should be issue behind this? Is there any configuration required?

Comment: Sounds great. Do you have proper antenna? GPS has cold hot starts go through with that

Comment: Okay. Specially which type of antenna required. I was thinking that we have to require some configuration like have to start AGPS or something to get GPS_STREAM.

Comment: Not sure never used that GPS

Comment: Okay. So, i think at-least we can receive proper data-stream and in mean time after power on the device if antenna could proper. Right?.

Comment: Yes but it might take 1-5 min to get started with cold start. If you have hot start supported 3-5 secs

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will back to you if any issue will occur.